# Is there any difference in meaning between "take someone" and "take someone on" in the sense of fighting with the person?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *take someone* and *take someone on* in the sense of fighting with the person? For example:

> Usyk is an exceptional fighter. I'm not really sure if can really **take**/**take on** a much bigger opponent, like Joshua or Fury, though.

Comment: I think that most people would probably agree that prepositionless *I could take him* is far more "slangy" than *I could take him on* for the *I'm confident I could beat him* (in a physical ***or*** other "contest", such as a debate). BUT in your cited context they're probably not synonymous anyway. If Usyk can take Joshua, that means he can ***beat*** him - but in order for Usyk to take on Joshua, he only has to be good enough to put up a decent fight (with a *reasonable* chance of winning, which is all that's needed as a precondition for the fight to take place at all).

Comment: (To take someone on = to ***fight*** them. To take them = to ***beat*** them.)

Comment: I've just waded through ***61*** definitions of ***take*** in Collins dictionary, and they don't actually list the prepositionless slang usage defined at [onlineslangdictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/take) as *to defeat in a fight. **Always used in a question or affirmation**.* So I suggest you avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**take someone on** = challenge someone in some sort of contest. This is often used when somebody decides to take part in a match trying to defeat a strong opponent. It implies that it would be difficult to achieve but that the challenger is also of a reasonable standard and might have a chance:

> I need a lot more practice before I could think about **taking you on** in tennis.

A variation of this can also be used when talking about tasks, implying that the task is somewhat burdensome.

> I can't **take on** a new project right now because I haven't finished the current one.

**take someone** = (an informal phrase meaning) beat someone in a contest. This is probably more common when talking about future or imagined situations.

> I think I could **take you** at chess.  I've been playing a lot and you don't seem that good.

This isn't usually used about tasks in the same way as above.